# Rails app connection with advantage database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, advantage-database-server

I'm trying to connect a Rails app 3.2.13 with an advantage database. I keep taking this error when I run rake db:create. 
Any suggestions what I could do to fix that?
Thank you!

```
C:\Users\Droste\rails_proj\lo_app>rake db:create --trace
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:create
rake aborted!
LoadError: Could not load ACE library
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-advantage-adapter-0.1.1/lib/act
ive_record/connection_adapters/advantage_adapter.rb:34:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/singleton.rb:141:in `new'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/singleton.rb:141:in `block in instance'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/singleton.rb:139:in `instance'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-advantage-adapter-0.1.1/lib/act
ive_record/connection_adapters/advantage_adapter.rb:60:in `advantage_connection'

C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railti
es/databases.rake:102:in `create_database'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railti
es/databases.rake:62:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railti
es/databases.rake:62:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railti
es/databases.rake:62:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.1/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.1/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block i
n execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.1/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.1/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute
'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.1/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block i
n invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.1/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_
with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.1/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'

C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.1/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `
invoke_task'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `
block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `
each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `
block in top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `
run_with_threads'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `
top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `b
lock in run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.1/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `
standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `r
un'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>
'
C:/Ruby193/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby193/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two .dll files from an older installation. I removed those and the connection looks ok.